# Crop part of an image and paste it into another with Imagemagick does not work

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two images and I want to crop a part of the first one, and paste it into the other one in a specific place using imagemagick. Also the crop part would be gray

I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gxSP.jpg

But I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzWWg.jpg

I have tried:

```
convert source.jpg ( +clone -crop 240x270+595+140 -resize 112x146 -type Grayscale ) -geometry +10+200 -composite destiny.jpg
```

but as you see, it does not works as expected.

Although the crop part is cloned as gray, the whole first image is cloned too, but I need to keep in background the second image in color and the crop part in gray in front of it.

Some ideas?

Comment: How about providing the images you started with? Did you start with John Doe or the blue one or the grey one?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you started with - please provide `source.jpg`, or something I can use instead.

Comment: Ok, good, I start with John Doe (source.jpg). And I crop the photo of it to paste it into the blue one (destiny.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot work out the simple image you start with nor what you expect to get - your question currently doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in chat, I think you need something along these lines - you may need to fiddle with the actual numbers but hopefully the concept is clear:

```
convert other.jpg \( source.jpg -crop 240x270+595+140 -colorspace gray -resize 116x150! \) -geometry +4+108 -composite result.png
```